# Solving the inhomogeneous two dimensional heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, greens-function, fundamental-solution

I am currently interested in solving the inhomogeneous heat equation for a two dimensional flow for a bounded domain. The PDE is given as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/feVBg.jpg

I was thinking about solving this by using the Fundamental solution as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsADx.jpg

with

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwm53.jpg

However since the inhomogeneous function is given as a rather "complicated" structure in terms of integration, I struggle quiete a lot there.

Do you have any ideas or experience in how to solve suche an inhomogeneous heat equation?

I would also appreciate any guidance in how to solve the inhomogeneous heat equation in genereal for a two dimensional flow.

I am very thankful for any advice

Comment: Please use MathJax for the future - makes it much easier for us to solve your doubts :)

Comment: Thanks @DhanviSreenivasan for your reply. I will keep it in mind. Sorry for that, it was my first post ever on this forum.